# Deploy ESPv2 locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, envoyproxy

I have successfully deployed ESPv2 on CloudRun.

Since ESPv2 is based on Envoy, I was wondering if there a way to deploy ESPv2 locally on my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. There's a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/running-esp-localdev)  that tells you how to run ESP locally or on another platform such as AWS or on a Kubernetes cluster that's not running on Google Cloud. I highly recommend that you study it first but I will try summarize it.

The guide is also applicable for ESPv2.

Take note that Windows is not yet supported and there are a few prerequisites before you can run the ESPv2 container on your machine:

1. You should have Docker installed on your machine.
2. You have deployed an API locally or on a host that is reachable to the host where you run ESPv2.
3. You've set-up Cloud Endpoints and deployed the configuration to create a service for your API.

You also need to provide a [service account JSON file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) with the following roles:

- Service Controller
- Cloud Trace Agent

because ESPv2 uses the service account details to generate access tokens to call the services to manage your API.

Sample command to run using Docker on Linux:

```
sudo docker run \
    --detach \
    --name="esp" \
    --net="host" \
    --volume=$HOME/Downloads:/esp \
    --publish=8082 \
    gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1 \
    --service=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME \
    --rollout_strategy=managed \
    --http_port=8082 \
    --backend=localhost:8080 \
    --service_account_key=/esp/service-account-creds.json
```

Comment: Note - after discussing the the GCP devs it seems that this doesn't work if you have the backend section in your api_config.yml file you use to create a remote proxy service on Google Cloud Run.