# How do I handle running things like Google Cloud API Gateway locally?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-api-gateway

I have a project that uses API gateway to handle security. When it does this it forwards the header to `x-forwarded-authorization` and a bunch of other stuff. Is there a way to recreate this so a dev can run all of these locally?

I see tickets like this ([Serverless API Gateway on GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127596/serverless-api-gateway-on-gcp)) suggest ESPv2 (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2)

Or I know I can throw something together with a reverse proxy like NGINX but what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to run the API gateway locally, and it appears that this [feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/193919691) is not available at this time. This is perhaps because Google API Gateway is built on [envoy](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/deployment-model) and it's tightly integrated with other [live services](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/architecture-overview).

If you need a local setup that is close to API Gateway's functionality, use [ESPv2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2) on your local machine. ESPv2 integrates with Google Service Infrastructure to enable API management features at scale, including authentication, telemetry reports, metrics, and security. You can check this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909962/deploy-espv2-locally) on how to deploy ESPv2 locally.